# Запуск камеры через сервис

Tags: java, android

Подскажите,как реализовать правильно такой алгоритм:
создал сервис:

```
public class ServiceCamera extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

данный сервис должен запускаться сразу после нажатия на икноку приложения, приложение без активити,т.е нажали на значек запустился сервис ,который в свою очередь выполнил действие на запуск камеры.
как запустить камеру через сервис и начать записывать видео?

Comment: гляньте тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976614/open-run-camera-from-background-service-in-android  и тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/taking-picture-from-camera-without-preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Совсем без Активити не получится, нужно хотя бы без разметки, в котором вызовется метод `finish();` сразу после запуска.

Как правильно создавать сервис, можно посмотреть здесь - Service. Простой пример. _http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/157-urok-92-service-prostoj-primer.html

Далее, автоматический старт камеры в Андроиде невозможен начиная с API 23 - сначала потребуется получить динамические разрешения. Немного о них рассказано на Хабрахабре - Android runtime permissions _https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/ - для работы с ними тоже потребуется Активити.

Третье - запись видео с камеры. Очень простой пример показан здесь - [Recording Video Simple](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html). Это официальная документация, но она на английском. Я думаю, вам не составит труда понять основной код.

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!